# How to set Data or Communicate with Property in UserControl As New Window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I just Started with WPF MVVM but i stuck on a point. I want to define the problem as Point.

1. I created a UserControl with one ComboBox(Binded with "Data" Property) and One Button (UserControl1.xaml).
2. Added to UserControl1 to MainWindow.xaml in Grid As
3. Created a Class1.vb With Public Property with INOtifyPropertyChange
4. Binded using
5. Binded Button with ICommand.

Everything is Working as button is working , combobox showing Data Properly but....

6. I added another UserControl As UserControl2.Xaml
7. Added another ComboBox(binded with "Data1" property) in UserControl2
8. UserControl2 is also binded with Class1
9. On Button i am setting two things 
   i)  Setting Data1 = Data (So value of Data set to Data1 on button click)
   ii) Initializing the UserControl2 As Window by
        Dim win As New Window with {.Content = New UserControl2}
   10) On button click from UserControl1 the Window is Showing but Data is not there which is binded on Usercontrol2 Combobox

I have tried  dataContext on code behind in xaml.vb

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 ></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.Xaml :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext >
        <local:Class1 ></local:Class1>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl } , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestBut ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl} , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Class1.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Class1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _data As String()
    Private _data1 As String()
    Private _testBut As ICommand
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Sub OnPropertyChange(prop As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop))
    End Sub

    Public Property Data As String()
        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(value As String())
            _data = value
            OnPropertyChange("Data")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TestBut As ICommand
        Get
            Return New Command(AddressOf test)
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)
            _testBut = value
            OnPropertyChange("TestBut")

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Data1 As String()
        Get
            Return _data1
        End Get
        Set(value As String())
            _data1 = value
            OnPropertyChange("Data1")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub test(obj As Object)
        Data1 = Data
        Dim win As New Window With {.Content = New UserControl2,
        .DataContext = Data1}
        win.Show()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        Data = New String() {"test", "test1", "test2", "test3"}
    End Sub

End Class
```

UserControl2

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <User
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to minimize the code in code behind (xaml.vb) as much possible as i want no code in xaml.vb, also I want to set communication between two usercontrol 
i hope you can enlighten me on this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Same Data in both usercontrol why cant you bind same "Data" instead of binding "Data1" in UserControl2?

Please see the modification. I have assigned datacontext in UserControl2.xaml. And changed combobox itemsource binding to Data

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext >
        <local:Class1 ></local:Class1>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the Function Test, i removed setting datacontext as we are already setting in xaml

```
 Private Function test()

        Dim win As New Window With {.Content = New UserControl2
        }
        win.Show()
    End Function
```

I am able to populate combo box in usercontrol 2 .

Edit : Problem why you are not able to see the data with assigning "Data1", once you create the new usercontrol , new instance of view model will be created and you are assigning "Data1=Data" before creating new window instance . 
I have modified the code as per your suggestion .

```
 Private Function test()
        Dim customer3 As Class1
        customer3 = New Class1()
        Dim win As New Window With {.Content = New UserControl2, .DataContext = customer3
        }
        Dim classObject = CType(win.DataContext, Class1)
        classObject.Data1 = Data
        win.Show()

    End Function
```

Xaml will be using "Data1" object as itemsource

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please ignore poor naming

Comment: Yeah even i removed DataContext from the buttoon. but my point is if i want to change something from "Data" and the changed data need to show in another control (in my case usercontrol2) then it's became blank . i debugged the code but everytime when another window is executed the property(Data1) became null